# .htacess returns 404 when url has a full stop/dot in it

Tags: .htaccess

I have this rewrite rule which works for the most part but returns a 404 when the URL has a full stop in it. for example "t.a.c._heroes" makes it error.

**This is my rule**

```
RewriteRule ^search/([^/\.]+)/?$ /index.php?page=search&string=$1 [NC,L]
```

I looked in the previous similar questions on stackoverflow and they said to try the following but these don't work either.

```
RewriteRule ^search/(.*)/?$ /index.php?page=search&string=$1 [NC,L]
```

Also tried this:

```
RewriteRule ^search/([^/.]*)/?$ /index.php?page=search&string=$1 [NC,L]
```

Thanks

Comment: Why do you want to exclude full stops in the search term? `(.*)` should always match whatever you put in your search term, so what error do you get then?

Comment: Show us your **complete** .htaccess, in case there's something else in there that's messing it up. Show an example or two that works, and one or two that fail.

Comment: `RewriteRule ^search/(.*)/?$ /index.php?page=search&string=$1 [NC,L]` should work fine. What URL is isn't working for you?